# регенерация паролей + брутфорс

Tags: c++, генераторы, брутфорс

вообщем у меня есть генератор паролей, создается динамический массив с типом чар длинна массива зависит от того какую длину пароля хочет пользователь, дальше я создаю свич и указываю что он рандомно будет выбирать 3 кейса и в этих кейсах я записываю в наш динамичиский массив число которое равно по системе ASCII какому-то символу далее, и делаю это столько раз сколько пользователь ввел длину пароля после вывожу фором все элементы массива и получается пароль. Вопрос в том как запихнуть получившееся в другой массив (полностью весь пароль) т.е. Я хочу что бы был массив с паролями которые вышли после генерации через свич

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


int main() {
setlocale(0, "ru");
srand(time(NULL));
cout << "Введи длину пароля: " << endl;
int a;
cin >> a;
char* password = new char[a];

for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        switch (rand() % 3)
        {
        case 0: {
            password[i] = 48 + rand() % 9;
            break;
        }
        case 1: {
            password[i] = 65 + rand() % 25;
            break;
        }
        case 2: {
            password[i] = 97 + rand() % 25;
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
for (int vivod = 0; vivod < a; vivod++) {
    cout << password[vivod];
}



}
```

Если поместить пароли в массив через чар и такой генератор паролей не получается то меняйте, но желательно  так, я новичок, и буду рад любой критике, заранее Огромное спасибо

Comment: ГСЧ из функции rand() не годен для криптографии

Answer (score 0):

зачем так сложно то?

1. создаете массив разрешённых символов (в вашем случае буквы + цифры - 59 символов)
2. дальше считаете, что у вас есть огромное число

   ```
    0000..00
   ```

кол-во нулей равно кол-ву символов в массиве

3. и начинаете увеличивать ваше число на 1

только в вашем случае у вас будет 59-ричная система счисления (т.е. размером с массив разрешённых символов)

4. каждое такое "число" потом переводите в соответствующую строку, где каждой цифре "числа" ставите в соответствие букву из массива разрешенных символов